# AX3000 "No Wifi Adapter Found" but bluetooth works

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 21.04

I just got the AX3000 in and the bluetooth works just fine, however the wifi does not.  Oh yeah, I'm running Ubuntu 21.04.  I've been using an ethernet cable for a long time now, but I'm now in a situation where a wifi connection would be ideal if not necessary.

I hear it's plug and play for some, and not for others, so I kind of expected it to not work out of the box.  After plugging it in, the bluetooth worked just fine, however ubuntu says there's no wifi adapter.

So I did some searching, and then went to the intel website and grabbed the proper drivers.  That didn't work, so I went to the git page they linked and downloaded the whole thing, then copied all the drivers for all the possible cards into the firmware folder.  That didn't work either.

I also got the backport package at some point as well.

I searched some more, and found that someone did `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`, which is a wonderful idea, so I tried it and nothing came up.  I tried just dmesg by its self and looked for anything even closely related and I haven't found anything other than all the fully-functional bluetooth stuff.

Here's `rfkill -list`, because some other posts have that as well.

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I'm not really sure what I can do at this point.  I usually don't write forum posts (if that wasn't obvious already :P) but I don't really know what else to try.  Oh, and is there any other info I should give?  Thanks!

EDIT:
No, though knowing what I know now I probably would have had a bit of an easier time finding something linux-compatable.  I got a... FebSmart AX3000?  I dunno.  It said it worked with linux, and the manual says to go get the drivers off of intel's website under the name of "AX200NGW".  Sounds to me like they just wrapped a bluetooth chip and that intel chip up and put it on a pcie express card.
`lspci` returns this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th/9th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 540a (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. XPG SX8200 Pro PCIe Gen3x4 M.2 2280 Solid State Drive (rev 03)
```

EDIT 2:
`sudo lsmod | grep iwl` returns nothing.

I've tried two different PCIe x1 slots now, both have the same results.  I also don't dual boot windows, since VMs are just way easier to use and swap between.  My kernel is at 5.11, so I'll try updating that real quick.

EDIT 3:

I tried a different PCIe x1 slot, that didn't work either.

BIOS version: 2.60

Motherboard: MSI Z370-A, 911-7B48-005

Comment: By AX3000 do you mean [this type of adapter/card (this is a NewEgg product link)](https://www.newegg.com/asus-pce-ax3000-pci-express/p/N82E16833320448?Description=ax3000)?  What does `lspci` show?

Comment: Edited the post to have more info. @ThomasWard

Comment: I don't see it in your lspci and I expected to. Maybe shutdown and make sure it's seated properly. You can try `sudo lsmod| grep iwl` first, but if it's not showing in lspci ... Or maybe it's there and I missed it?

Comment: I'm working the same issue at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377600/tplink-ax3000-not-working-with-ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-init-ucode-110 but haven't found a solution yet. Read that thread and check for the same things that we did there, and maybe we can get more info for both of you. Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Comment: there's not much explanation but I saw a reddit user claimed kernel 5.12 fixed an issue. You can use `uname -r` to check if you're running 5.11 or below. see https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qcdnv1/trouble_installing_asx3000_wifi6_card_iwlwifi/

Comment: See the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269313/ax200-wifi-and-20-04/1271055#1271055

Comment: What type of port did you plug your adapter into?  The AX3000 works best in a PCIe x1 slot per other research i did supporting the other question/answer linked here by heynnema.  If you put it in a x16 slot it might not work right.

Comment: Try a different slot as the wifi chipset isn't detected at all

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @JupiterSky Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I'm in the middle of the move and the semester is coming to an end.  Bios version is `2.60`, and the motherboard is `MSI Z370-A pro LGA 1151`, model number `911-7B48-005`.

Comment: @JupiterSky See the BIOS update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows**

If you dual-boot with Windows, disable **Fast Startup** and **hibernation** in Windows:

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:
- reboot into Ubuntu and see if the wifi card works now

**AX3000**

If you have both PCIe x1 and PCIe x16 slots on your motherboard:

- Insert the AX3000 into a PCIe x1 slot, where it should work.

**BIOS**

MSI Z370-A pro LGA 1151

You have an older BIOS, version 2.60. There's a newer BIOS available at https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z370-A-PRO/support#down-bios

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm currently sending this message over wifi!  I can't use my ethernet cable where we're going for one reason or another, so this was a literal lifesaver.  I am eternally grateful!  (BIOS update worked, I guess the card was too new for the very old bios to recognize.)

Comment: @JupiterSky Great news! Thanks for the update.